# Mediteranean Mathematics Olympiad 2014 number theory problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I paraphrase it slightly to make it shorter.

Prove for every integer $S\geq100$ there exists a positive integer $P$ such that there are at least two different solutions in positive integers(up to permutation of $(a,b,c)$) to the system of equations:

$abc=P$

$a+b+c=S$

---

I am completely stumped here, I am having difficulties coming up with examples of $S$ that work.

Comment: Well for the beginning I would assume  $c=1$ and try to analyze $ab=P,a+b=S-1$  equation. It is solvable and we can set conditions for $P,S$ to get integer solutions....

Comment: It is easy to prove if you have to two solutions then all of the numbers are different.

Comment: I feel like there might be some way to construct solutions for larger $S$ out of solutions for smaller $S$. To that end, here are the solutions for $S\le 22$: \begin{align*}\{1, 6, 6\},& \{2, 2, 9\}\\
\{1, 5, 8\},& \{2, 2, 10\}\\
\{2, 6, 6\},& \{3, 3, 8\}\\
\{2, 5, 9\},& \{3, 3, 10\}\\
\{3, 6, 8\},& \{4, 4, 9\}\\\{2, 8, 9\},& \{3, 4, 12\}\\
\{1, 9, 10\},& \{2, 3, 15\}\\
\{3, 8, 10\},& \{4, 5, 12\}\\
\{2, 7, 12\},& \{3, 4, 14\}\\
\{1, 8, 12\},& \{2, 3, 16\}\\
\{5, 8, 9\},& \{6, 6, 10\}\end{align*}
Anybody see a way to bootstrap from these...?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner There is a unique (up to permutation) solution to your system of equations. A necessary and sufficient condition for the solutions to be integers is that the discriminant is a perfect square.

Comment: I just said I would start from this. I did not claim I solved the problem.

Comment: FYI, I think that is a good start. I was continuing your chain of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explicit solution quoted from some training material from China. (The construction pops out from nowhere, maybe someone can clarify it)

Take a positive integer $m$ such that $\frac{n}{22}<m<\frac{n}{17}$.
Then $$(2m, 4(n-17m), 3(22m-n)$$ and $$(2(n-17m), 22m-n, 12m)$$ are the desired answer. (Delicate checking needed.)

Answer (score 1):

Given, $abc=P$, $a+b+c=S$. Hence, $ab=P/c$ and $a+b=S-c$ or $x^2-(S-c)x+P/c=0$, but the determinant must be a square, so, $(S-c)^2-4P/c=r^2$, for some integer $r$. Let $P/c=k^2$ so that $(S-c)^2=(2k)^2+r^2$ a pythagora's equation with $S-c=l^2+m^2$, $k=lm$ and $r=l^2-m^2$. So the solution of the quadratic, which solves for $a$ and $b$, is $a=l^2$, $b=m^2$, and $c=S-(l^2+m^2)$ and $P=k^2c=(lm)^2c=l^2m^2[S-(l^2+m^2)]$

Comment: Can you clarify, how does this give us 2 sets of a, b, c?